# Looping over an array - getting every other item?

Tags: c#, .net, nini

I have a `.ini` file
the .ini:

```
;app ...

    [MSGS]

    title#0 = first title.. 
    message#0 = first message 

    title#1 = second title
    message#1 = second message 

    title#2 = third title
    message#2 = third message
```

I'm using  the [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/) lib for parsing. I need read it to a dictionary.

I tried this:

```
 public Dictionary<string, string> Read()
        {
            try
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                IConfigSource src = config;
                IConfig values = src.Configs["MSGS"];
                string[] keys = values.GetKeys();

                for (int count = keys.Length / 2,i = 0, j = 1; 
                        i < count; i++, 
                        j = i + 1)
                {
                    string titleKey = keys[i];
                    string messageKey = keys[j];
                    string titleVal = values.Get(titleKey);
                    string messageVal = values.Get(messageKey);
                    result.Add(titleVal, messageVal);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            return null;
        }
```

The output is:

```
first title.. : first message
first message : second title
second title : second message
```

I want:

```
first title.. : first message
second title : second message
third title : third message
```

How I do this? 
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What's the second loop variable `j` doing there, apart from introducing bugs?

Comment: Closers - this is a valid programming question. Not "too localized" at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i += 2)
            {
                string titleKey = keys[i];
                string messageKey = keys[i+1];
                string titleVal = values.Get(titleKey);
                string messageVal = values.Get(messageKey);
                result.Add(titleVal, messageVal);
            }
```

Comment: good solution, I was a bit confusing about the i variable incrementation.

Comment: Yes I noticed. :) You were counting up to half the items, but you weren't multiplying your title-indexer by 2, which is why it wasn't working. But I figured counting to full length and incrementing by 2 would be cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: @Mithon Sorry to grave dig on this post, but is there a way to combine the `=+2` within the built-in `foreach` statement?

Comment: @Austin Not really. The main issue here is that the input data is unstructured and there is meaning connected to the positioning in the keys collection. So you could do something to group each pair of keys first and then foreach those pairs. But grouping those pairs would involve some sort of += 2 loop or some Linq shinanigans. That sort of code, while feasible, will be less performant, longer and more confusing.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many variables in your loop - the `j` and `count` are not needed and only serve to confuse matters:

```
for (i = 0; i < keys.Length; i += 2)
{
  string titleKey = keys[i];
  string messageKey = keys[i + 1];
  string titleVal = values.Get(titleKey);
  string messageVal = values.Get(messageKey);
  result.Add(titleVal, messageVal);
}
```

Comment: you're right,in parts. the count variables is necessary for performance reasons.

Comment: @TheMask - For this amount of looping, what you gain in "performance" you loose several times over in readability, maintainability and introduction of bugs.

Comment: then, `i < keys.Length;` is faster that `c = keys.length; i < c;` ?

Comment: @TheMask - I didn't say that. It is probably a bit slower - you would only notice the different over millions (or billions) of iterations. This is a _micro-optimization_ that is not likely to be useful.

Comment: maybe in C# this micro-optimization that can't be useful. in C++ the difference it is notable in lines little.